# Need common arrays from two multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hi I have below multidimensional arrays -

```
Array
(
    [user_attempts] => 0
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 32
            [1] => 23
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => asdsa
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Earth
        )

)
```

and my second array is like below

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Earth
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 32
            [1] => 23
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => asdsa
            [1] => asdas
        )

)
```

I need to intersect both multidimensional arrays - so the result would be

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Earth
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 32
            [1] => 23
        )
)
```

Can anyone help me to sort this out.

What I have tried is using array_intersect() but it limits to single array not multidimensional i guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the easier to compare you can use `serialize/unserialize` on this one. And then use `array_intersect()`. Try this example: [**Sample Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Pd2Zi4)

```
$array1 = array( 'user_attemps' => 0, 2 => array(1, 4), 3 => array(32, 23), 4 => array('asdsa'), 1 => array('Earth'),);
$array2 = array( 1 => array('Earth'), 2 => array(2, 3), 3 => array(32, 23), 4 => array('asdsa', 'asdas'),);
$result = array_map('unserialize',array_intersect(array_map('serialize', $array1), array_map('serialize', $array2)));
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP comes with a ton of functions already built in, but sometimes you still have to implement things yourself. What you want to do can be easily done by using the existing functions.

The goal is to do the following steps:

1. Find the keys that exist in both arrays
2. Loop through the array using these keys
3. Take the items of both input arrays with each of these keys
4. Calculate the intersection of those two arrays
5. Put it into a result array

Here is one way to do this:

```
function array_intersect_2dim (array $a1, array $a2) {
    $keys = array_intersect(array_keys($a1), array_keys($a2));
    $return = array();
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        $return[$key] = array_intersect($a1[$key], $a2[$key]);
        if (sizeof($return[$key]) == 0) {
            unset($return[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

It works only for two dimensions. If you need more, you have to build a recursive approach, which follows the exact same principle.